# jquery mover imagen sin salir del div contenedor

Tags: jquery

Utilizando jquery debo crear: una página provista de una imagen y cuatro botones:

```
“Arriba”, “Abajo”, “Izquierda”, “Derecha”.
```

Cada botón al ser pulsado debe desplazar la imagen 1 pixel en la dirección correspondiente. Para ello debes crear cuatro funciones de javascript:

```
 MoverArriba(), MoverAbajo(), MoverIzquierda(), y MoverDerecha()
```

Cada una de las cuales modificar la posición de la imagen 1 píxel en la dirección correspondiente. Emplea únicamente una función de JavaScript llamada Mover. Esta función deberá recibir como único parámetro un valor que indique la dirección del movimiento de la imagen. La función debe evitar que la imagen salga de los límites visibles de la pantalla.

```html
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>anexo5-pag24-ej2</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Crea una página provista de una imagen y cuatro botones: “Arriba”, “Abajo”,
    “Izquierda”, “Derecha”. Cada botón al ser pulsado debe desplazar la imagen 1
    pixel en la dirección correspondiente. Para ello debes crear cuatro funciones de
    javascript: MoverArriba(), MoverAbajo(), MoverIzquierda(), y MoverDerecha()
    cada una de las cuales modificar la posición de la imagen 1 píxel en la dirección
    correspondiente.  -->


  <div id="div1" style="border: 5px solid black; width: 400px; height: 400px;">
    <img src="./assets/super-mario.jpg" alt="imagen" id="imagen">
  </div>
  <button id="arriba">Arriba</button>
  <button id="abajo">Abajo</button>
  <button id="izquierda">Izquierda</button>
  <button id="derecha">Derecha</button>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#arriba").click(function() {
        $("#imagen").animate({
          top: "-=10px"
        }, 0);
      });
      $("#abajo").click(function() {
        $("#imagen").animate({
          top: "+=10px"
        }, 0);
      });
      $("#izquierda").click(function() {
        $("#imagen").animate({
          left: "-=10px"
        }, 0);
      });
      $("#derecha").click(function() {
        $("#imagen").animate({
          left: "+=10px"
        }, 0);
      });

    });
  </script>
  <style>
    #imagen {
      position: absolute
    }
    
    #div1 {
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Y Sabes como mover la imagen sin salir del div? Que al llegar al limite del div la imagen se detena y no se mueva mas? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sí, bueno, a ver, es un ejercicio, el cual no estás haciendo bien porque por un lado te dicen esto: `Emplea únicamente una función de JavaScript llamada Mover.` y no lo estás haciendo (aún), y por el otro no te piden que no salga de un `<div>`, sinó esto: `La función debe evitar que la imagen salga de los límites visibles de la pantalla.`.  Aunque te de una solución no te va a servir para solucionar tu ejercicio y será una pérdida de tiempo para ambos.

Comment: Por otra parte, lo siento pero no veo ningún intento por solucionar el ejercicio, al menos lo que pides en el título de la pregunta, y así no ayudamos, pues no tienes ningún error, tan solo nos estás pasando la tarea a nosotros, y así no funciona este sitio. Por favor, léete [ask] (donde pone **Busca e investiga**), haz el [tour] y cuando lo intentes pon un [example] de tu intento y los errores que te ha dado, gracias. De este modo se te podrá ayudar mejor y sin que nadie se queje de una posible respuesta por mi parte ante una pregunta así, lo siento.